# Can you make a mailchimp form validate on onsite

Tags: forms, webforms, wufoo

I've made a mailchimp newsletter form with two fields; Name and Email. When i click it obviously loads the page where the designed form is to on my mailchimp account. How would i go about make it all work on my site and just post the information over to mailchimp.. my goal is not to have the user leaving the splash page.

I did try just including the java include code and that seems to do everthing on the page as i want, but then i can't style the form because it's pulling in all it's styles from Wufoo.

Regards
M

Comment: Would Wufoo grant you a license to copy their styles on your web server, so you could load those from your system too?

Comment: i found i can style the form now, but it's the way in which it's validating thats frustrating. I dont want it to load an esternal page to validate any errors etc. Trying to find out how to stop it from doing this